# Introducing: Jobs in your Sidebar

Tags: discussion

See that mini job board in the right panel on your site? We are testing out a new feature on a couple Stack Exchange sites. It's a jobs widget that displays several geo-targeted job postings specific to your community. These job posts are contained in a small (we hope unobtrusive) display below the Community Bulletin on the sidebar. For this early version, job listings are provided from the database at Indeed.com. If your area of interest is not represented or the level of expertise of roles presented doesn't match what you'd find most useful, we want to know. This is very much a work in progress.

We think GIS is an ideal candidate to try out this early version. You have specialized skills, your skills are in demand, and we suspect that many of you may be interested in exploring new career opportunities.

Please let us know what you think.

Answer (score 6):

I like the idea. Would there be any way to target the jobs by logged-in user location? While I'd love to spend some time working in the US one day, for the moment it's a long way from home.

Answer (score 6):

It seems like the jobs may already be listed by user-location, which is nice in theory, but not necessarily in practice.  I'm working for the Fed, and our IT Network is based out of Colorado, and all of the jobs seem to be located there.

**If job postings are based on location of the user, there should be an option to manually designate your location.**

Comment: At the moment manually designating location isn't doable - but hopefully we can make this possible in the future!

Comment: +1 On the user's profile gis.SE could provide a map with markers representing job locations of interest, and use those to populate the sidebar.  Could also use keywords from the user's profile to target jobs.

Answer (score 5):

Well, this is a great idea in theory, the problem is that indeed.com thinks that GIS also has something to do with [Gastroenterology](http://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=gis&l=Fayetteville,%20AR):

[image]

Comment: I could sometimes use a Gastroenterologist when sifting through the ESRI docs...

Comment: There was a similar set of physician related ads on the stats site yesterday, but they are no more today. Perhaps it was a mistake.

Comment: @AndyW - Yep, I see the changes now.

Comment: Wait, still see medical field jobs.

Comment: The related jobs box has been blank for me since it was implemented, except for the title.

Comment: Do you use an ad blocker such as AdBlock Plus?

Comment: @blah238 - Nope, no adblocker at all.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is a good idea in theory.  However, the same jobs have been listed since the feature became available.  If Garmin hasn't filled the Cartography Technician position in Olatha, KS in all this time, there's a problem.

Plus, as previously mentioned, it doesn't show other countries. Just USA.  I live in Australia and this feature is just spam for me.

Answer (score 3):

It is definitely a good idea. I'm looking forward to it.

Answer (score 1):

I would love to see listings of jobs working with open source GIS stacks!

Answer (score 1):

Does it even work? I'm from Slovenia and the box is always blank, with only the title in there. I suggest a fallback along the lines of "No near/suitable jobs found." for such cases.

Comment: There aren't jobs available in the database for all locations unfortunately. Good suggestion for the future, thanks.